# Updating Target records of the same object dynamically

Tags: apex, fieldsets

I need to update fields value on the target record , with the fields values on the source records dynamically. (Both records of the same object).
I am trying to use FieldSets. Below is something which I am trying-

```
for(Schema.FieldSetMember field : SObjectType.Account.FieldSets.AccountFieldSet.getFields()) {
    TargetRecord.field.getFieldPath() =  SourceRecord.field.getFieldPath();}
```

It throws error. I also tried `target.field.getSObjectField() = source.field.getSObjectField();`

This throws error too, **field doesn't exist.** 
I have gone through dynamic apex salesforce documents, but still it's not clear. Can someone point in a right direction?
**Example-** Account target, source (these 2 records already exist in database)
let's say we have a field- Language__c on Account, then I want

```
target.Langauge__c = source.Language__c;
Update target;
```

I want these field to be configured in fieldsets and use these, so that next time, when any new field needs to be mapped, I needn't update my code, rather just add that field in fieldsets

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the `put()` method for this.

```
for(Schema.FieldSetMember field : SObjectType.Account.FieldSets.AccountFieldSet.getFields()) {
    String fieldName = field.getName(); 
    targetRecord.put(fieldName, sourceRecord.get(fieldName);
}
```

Information regarding the `put()` and `get()` methods as they pertain to SObjects can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm).

Comment: How do I update the TargetRecord? Targetrecord is an instance of Account

Comment: have you already tried "update targetRecord;"?

Comment: @ManishAnand Can you elaborate? Are you referring to setting the value for the TargetRecord, or referring to actually committing the record to the database?

Comment: I am trying to set the value for the TargetRecord and then update the TargetRecord.

Comment: @ManishAnand The `put()` method sets the value for TargetRecord. From there you can use DML operations to update the Target Record.

Comment: I have added an example. I will try above option and let you know.